# Font size not available, actually not true

Tags: fontsize

I was given a Latex template that actually produces a PDF file, but with a lot of warnings. The template is based on the `article` class and has many customized `\newcommand` and `\newfontfamily` entries. A snippet of it follows:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{nokia}[2018/10/22 Nokia article class]
[...]
\LoadClass{article}
%% Nokia blue color definitions
\definecolor{nokiablue}{RGB}{18,65,145}
\definecolor{nokiadark}{RGB}{0,17,53}
%% Nokia fonts
\newfontfamily\nokiatitle[SizeFeatures={Size=22},Color=nokiablue{NokiaPureHeadline_Light.ttf}
\newfontfamily\nokiasubtitle[SizeFeatures={Size=11},Color=nokiadark]{NokiaPureText-Light.ttf}
\newfontfamily\nokiachangehistory[SizeFeatures={Size=9},Color=nokiadark]{NokiaPureText-Light.ttf}
[...]
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

After saving the file, VSCode pops up this warning a the line `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}` with this warning message.

```
Font shape `TU/NokiaPureText-Light.ttf(3)/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)  size <11> substituted.
```

Also, in the log file, I can read `LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

However, after inspectioning the `.ttf` file, I do see the size `<10>` in it.

[image]

Am I missing some configuration or misunderstanding something?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Please show a code example that gives this warning. Then we'll have a better idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Done, I've updated the question. thanks.

Comment: `SizeFeatures={Size=11}` does not set the size but specifies that this font can only be used at this size (normally used to select different fonts at different sizes which isn't done here). So you explicitly disallowed other sizes and then tried to use them anyway.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, thanks for the tip. Now, conceptually I do understand your explanation, but I'm not quite sure how to check where is it that I'm using those sizes anyway. Because the only place so far that I'm defining something related to sizes is in the definition of the `\newfontfamily`. any hint? thanks!